# what does the "n'dbname" what does the 'n' stand for and

Tags: sql-server, sql, scripting

```
USE [master] 
GO 
/****** Object:  Database [assist]    Script Date: 11/13/2010 20:17:49 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [assist] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'assist', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.THIRD\MSSQL\DATA\assist.mdf' , SIZE = 2304KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'assist_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.THIRD\MSSQL\DATA\assist_log.LDF' , SIZE = 504KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

In the above, what do the following terms mean/usage.

- `GO`?
- `N' within this statement "NAME = N'assist', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"You may have seen Transact-SQL code that passes strings around using an N prefix. This denotes that the subsequent string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set). Which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT. See Article #2354 for a comparison of these data types. "

[reference from aspfaq.com](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html)

Comment: and the remaining "go"?

Comment: The keyword GO tells SQL Server to execute the preceding code as one batch. Also, check out http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1216 which explains the ability to add a number after the GO keyword to tell SQL Server (2005+) how many times to execute the batch.